# How can I show an extra label in front of each  radio button list item  which have serial number?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list which I bind with the data source with the following code and it shows as the desired result for me:

```
dv.RowFilter = "VoteId = " + grdVote.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;
            rdbList.DataSource = dv;
            rdbList.DataTextField = "VoteOption";
            rdbList.DataValueField = "VoteOptionId";
            rdbList.DataBind();
```

Now my question is how can I show the alphabetical serial number with each radio button list items.in below image there should be 'A' before apple and 'B' before banana and so on.....

[image: extend radio button list to show serial number in front of each radio button list item]

Comment: @Flimzy you edit its with wrong title.i don't want to sort them .please read it carefully.and due to your edit my question title and its description are miss matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it will not be possible with radio button list unless you are ready to change your data source to have text values prefixed with letters (although that will also not generate the correct layout).

In general, I am not fan of markup (html) generated by radio button list and suggest using a repeater to get the layout with the correct semantic html. For example,

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="optionList">
   <HeaderTemplate><ol class="optionList" type="A"></HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate> 
     <li>
       <input type="radio" name="VoteList" value='<%# Eval("VoteOptionId") %>' />
       <%# Eval("VoteOption") %>
     </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate></ol></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

To access the selected radio-button, you can use `Request.Form["VoteList"]`

EDIT: If you must use radio button, one of the idea could be modifying the text once the list has been data-bound. For example,

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=0; i < rdbList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        rdbList.Items[i].Text = Convert.ToChar(65 + i).ToString() + " " + rdbList.Items[i].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: your idea is appreciable but i want to do it with radio button, and can i add an extra control in radio button list because it renders with table tr td and each td list items renders as  input type radio + one label for each item. so my idea is that can i add an extra label in that  td on radio button list data bound event . and set its text

Comment: i already tried it and instead of page prerender i tried it on rdblist_Prerender and the mistake is that it will give alphabets before the text (label) but i want these alphabets before the radio button circle(input type radio)

Comment: protected void rdbList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonList rdbList = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        foreach (ListItem li in rdbList.Items)
        {
            Label l1 = new Label();
            l1.Text = "a";
            
        }
    }

Comment: @rahularyansharma, `RadioButtonList` control model does not offer any way to add other controls to it. For better control over markup (such as alphabet before radio button), you need to use other control such as `Repeater` - not only that it offers flexibility but also you can generate valid semantic html (which is an ordered list in this case).

Comment: @vinayC whats the reason behind this ? is this any related to any interface which is not implemented by the radio button list ?

Comment: There is no particular reason other than MS team had decided to design it as such! IMO, the control should have been offering a list (`ol`/`ul`) as one of the layout option but sadly it doesn't. MS did offer such support for MenuList in .NET 4!

Comment: @VinayC thanks buddy for such useful info. and giving your precious time to my question.